# cpusets not working - threads aren't running in the cpuset I specified?

Tags: linux, scheduler

I have used `cpuset` to shield some cpus for exclusive use by some realtime threads.

Displaying the cpuset config with the test app `RealtimeTest1` running and its tasks moved into the cpusets:

```
$ cset set --list -r
cset: 
         Name         CPUs-X    MEMs-X Tasks Subs Path
 ------------   ---------- - ------- - ----- ---- ----------
         root         0-23 y     0-1 y   279    2 /
       system 0,2,4,6,8,10 n       0 n   202    0 /system
       shield 1,3,5,7,9,11 n       1 n     0    2 /shield
RealtimeTest1      1,3,5,7 n       1 n     0    4 /shield/RealtimeTest1
      thread1            3 n       1 n     1    0 /shield/RealtimeTest1/thread1
      thread2            5 n       1 n     1    0 /shield/RealtimeTest1/thread2
         main            1 n       1 n     1    0 /shield/RealtimeTest1/main
```

I can interrogate the `cpuset` filesystem to show that my tasks are *supposedly* pinned to the cpus I requested:

```
/cpusets/shield/RealtimeTest1 $ for i in `find -name tasks`; do echo $i; cat $i; echo "------------"; done

./thread1/tasks
17651 
------------
./main/tasks
17649 
------------
./thread2/tasks
17654
------------
```

Further, if I use `sched_getaffinity`, it reports what `cpuset` does - that thread1 is on cpu 3 and thread2 is on cpu 5.

However, if I run `top -p 17649 -H` with `f,j` to bring up the `last used cpu`, it shows that **thread 1 is  running on thread 2's cpu, and main thread is running on a cpu in the `system` cpuset**

(Note that thread 17654 is running FIFO, hence thread 17651 is blocked)

```
  PID USER      PR  NI  VIRT  RES  SHR S %CPU %MEM    TIME+  P COMMAND                                                                                                                                                                                             
17654 root      -2   0 54080  35m 7064 R  100  0.4   5:00.77 3 RealtimeTest                                                                                                                                                                                         
17649 root      20   0 54080  35m 7064 S    0  0.4   0:00.05 2 RealtimeTest                                                                                                                                                                                         
17651 root      20   0 54080  35m 7064 R    0  0.4   0:00.00 3 RealtimeTest
```

Also, looking at `/proc/17649/task` to find the `last_cpu` each of its tasks ran on:

```
/proc/17649/task $  for i in `ls -1`; do cat $i/stat | awk '{print $1 " is on " $(NF - 5)}'; done
17649 is on 2
17651 is on 3
17654 is on 3
```

**So `cpuset` and `sched_getaffinity` reports one thing, but reality is another**

I would say that `cpuset` is not working?

My machine configuration is:

```
$ cat /etc/SuSE-release
SUSE Linux Enterprise Server 11 (x86_64)
VERSION = 11
PATCHLEVEL = 1
$ uname -a
Linux foobar 2.6.32.12-0.7-default #1 SMP 2010-05-20 11:14:20 +0200 x86_64 x86_64 x86_64 GNU/Linux
```

**Update:**

Additionally I am parsing `/proc/pid/task/tid/stat` and calling `sched_getcpu()` before and after the `cset --move` call, and I'm also doing a `sched_yield()` after the pinning to try get the thread to move...

This is an example output:

```
13:12:56 INFO before pinning thread 17508 reports lastCpu=0, currCpu=1
13:12:56 INFO pinning thread 17508 to cpu 3 (/shield/RealtimeTest1/thread1)
13:12:56 INFO SetAffinity cset response:
    cset: moving following pidspec: 17508
    cset: moving 1 userspace tasks to /shield/RealtimeTest1/thread1
    cset: done
13:12:56 INFO after pinning thread 17508 reports lastCpu=0, currCpu=1
13:12:56 INFO after sch_yld thread 17508 reports lastCpu=0, currCpu=1
```

So the thread is not moving to its new cpuset immediately, or even after a `sched_yield`

**Could this be a SLES 11 / SP 1 issue?**

Comment: Unrelated: is Hyperthreading enabled?

Comment: @ewwhite It is, although I don't specify any of the ht cpus in my cpuset configuration.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have reran the tests on a **SLES 11 / SP 2** box, and the pinning works.

As such, I'm going to mark this as an answer, which is: This is an issue related to **SP 1**